# Sails 1.0 cannot access autogenerated associated entity routes

Tags: sails.js, one-to-many, waterline, apiblueprint

I have an association between Client and Budget as follows:

```
//Client.js
module.exports = {
  primaryKey: 'id',

  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    phone: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true
    },
    budgets: {
      collection: 'budget',
      via: 'client'
    },
  }
};


// Budget.js
module.exports = {
  primaryKey: 'id',

  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    client: {
      model: 'client'
    },
    budgetItems: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  }
};
```

So, POST is working for both entities so I can create both of them, but:

```
 GET /budget/1
```

returns the budget and the id of the associated client.

```
 GET /budget/1/client
```

returns the client id without populating(as i've seen in [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/populate-where#?example) it should be populated).

```
 GET /client/1
```

returns the client attributes and there is not a field related with budgets.

```
 GET /client/1/budgets
```

returns 404 NOT FOUND

I'm following [this](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations/one-to-many) and [this](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/populate-where#?example) official documentation

So what I could be missing?

Is just generating one direction associations, and I've compared with official documentation and third party examples and my code looks fine.

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

I still looking for troubles and if I run sails with `--silly` option it shows there is the following route available:

> Binding route ::  get /client/:parentid/budgets POLICY: localize
>   Binding route ::  get /client/:parentid/budgets POLICY: isauth
>   Binding route ::  get /client/:parentid/budgets BLUEPRINT: populate

but if I try to access returns a 404 Not Found and console shows the following error, thrown by populate.js from Sails core code:

> verbo: In `populate` blueprint action: Specified parent record (1)
>   does not have a `budgets`.

**Update2:**

Debugging with sails console I've seen the association is generated properly. Given `Client.findOne({id: 1}).populate('budgets').then((client)=>{console.log(client)})` print the client attributes and the associated Budgets but still return 404 Not Found when: `GET /client/1/budgets`

Comment: Have you opened an issue on the Sails repo? https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues

Comment: I've asked on glitter but no one knows what could be happening, like there. I didn't want to bother sails developers if it was my fault, so I'm going to open an issue. Thanks for your dedication, I'm going to update this post if I got news ;)

Comment: [Issue opened](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/6539)

Comment: can you give minimum repo to test with? I will try to help on it, sails is my favourite ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to SailsJS team we've found the problem and it was related with a third party package and just had to remove it from my project.
It was `sails-hook-deep-orm` who's owner has been warned. I hope someone with the same issue will reach this post.

Thanks u all anyway!!

The issue is available [there](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/6539)

Answer (score 1):

I have created quick demo and it seems working fine for me.

For demo I have used sails version **1.2.2** and **sails-disk** as database and there is some minor difference in Model attributes as below
Client.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
    phone: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true
    },
    budgets: {
      collection: 'Budget', // <<== B is capital here
      via: 'client'
    },
  },
};
```

Budget.js

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    client: {
      model: 'Client' // <<== C is capital here
    },
    budgetItems: {
      type: 'json'
    }
  },
};
```

Let me know if this is helpful