# How to upgrade Sails from 1.1.0 to 1.2.2

Tags: sails.js

I have a SailsJS project on 1.1.0 on which I having some troubles. I'm interested on upgrading it to 1.2.2 to see if those troubles can be fixed with the new version. Is recomendable to upgrade and do you think it could worth?

How to do it?
For sure it should be some easy npm commands but not sure which ones.

Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work with the upgrade switch so you'll have to do

```
npm install -g sails
```

It'll upgrade to the latest 1.2.2

Comment: Or install the sails upgrade tool:
```
npm install @sailshq/upgrade
'''
then do,
```
sails upgrade

``` The advantage with this is that it suggest what other packages you might need.

Comment: I've upgraded changing the version directly in package.json and thats old. Actually I'm running v1.2.2 but still having the same troubles :(. I've been unlucky but thank you anyway!

Comment: you're welcome! what specific troubles do you have?

Comment: Well, I have a question with no answer still from at least a week ago. Let's see if you can help. I basicly cannot acces via URL to associated nested entities in oneToMany relationships like Owner --> Pets like in the official documentation. [There](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165433/sails-1-0-cannot-access-autogenerated-associated-entity-routes) is my SO post. Have a look please :(